# jQuery add class on div loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my page i have a div loaded dynamically, and i want to add class after this div is loaded.

this is the div before loading :

```
<div id="billing-address"></div>
```

after loading :

```
<div id="billing-address">
<ul>
<li>A</li>
<li>B</li>
<li>C</li>
<li>D</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#billing-address').addClass('open');
});
```

Comment: How are you loading the div?

Answer (score 1):

Do the `addClass` in the callback when you load the DIV dynamically. For instance:

```
$("#billing-address").load("AJAXURL", function() {
    $(this).addClass("open");
});
```